# Should I keep extensions in their own "Extensions" file?

Tags: swift, extension-methods

I have a few extensions that I'd like to use throughout my project but I'm unsure if I should keep them in their own file, or if I should just make specific extensions in each viewController file.

Which would be more efficient or better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is largely a matter of style rather than efficiency. That said, yes you should put them in their own file. That way if you want to reuse them between projects, you can simply drag and drop them into a new project.

In general, it is best to keep your files as small and modular as possible in order to keep things simple. If a piece of functionality doesn't specifically pertain to that file or viewcontroller then I think you should break it into its own file.

Comment: Thank you. My project is growing and my view controller files are getting a bit unruly! I will put them in their own file.

Answer (score 0):

I usually make files following the naming convention of Objective-C categories which are similar.

So, I put my String extensions in "String+Extensions.swift" and my UIViewController extensions in "UIViewController+Extensions.swift"

If I want to sub-categorize even further, then I make more files with different words after the `+`.  In file names, to iOS devs that have done a lot of Objective-C, a `+` means "has categories" and for Swift files, means "has extensions".

Comment: Personal opinion, but that's the "wordy" Obj-C way of doing things. :-) My preference is to simply make an Xcode group called extensions and add files to it named by the class they extend. If you need to further break it down, say into UIViewController extensions for UIImagePickerConrollerDelegate and UITableControlDelegate, then maybe use a plus sign. :-)