# Protocol and Delegate Help? Value isn't passing back

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, delegates, protocols

I've got my `EditorViewController` that segues modally to my `ModalViewController`, and in the ModalViewController I have to pass some data back to the EditorViewController after the view is dismissed.  I've looked at many tutorials about delegates and protocols, and I believe that's what I have to do to pass this information, but I can't seem to get the code right although I've followed the tutorials exactly. If anyone can see what's going wrong in here I would appreciate it.  I'll post the code.

The protocol

```
protocol passColorBackDelegate {
    func colorToChange(_ color: String)
}
```

The first view Controller

```
class EditorViewController: UIViewController, passColorBackDelegate {

    func colorToChange(_ color: String) {
    print("Hello")
}
```

The second view Controller file (the one with data to pass back to first), also has another class in it, I'm stingy with my files

```
class subView: UIView {

}

class ModalViewController: UIViewController {

var delegate: passColorBackDelegate?

@IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender {
    case blueColorButton: colorToChangeTo = "Blue"
    case redColorButton: colorToChangeTo = "Red"
    case greenColorButton: colorToChangeTo = "Green"
    case purpColorButton: colorToChangeTo = "Purple"
    default: print("error")
    }
    print(colorToChangeTo)
    delegate?.colorToChange(colorToChangeTo)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

As you can see my protocol function doesn't include any of the data I need passed back yet, but the message still isn't printing, meaning the function isn't getting called.  If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I would appreciate it.  Thanks

Comment: Are you setting the delegate before you segue? You would need to do something like this: `modalViewController.delegate = self`.

Comment: Where would I put that line of code? In `viewDidLoad()` or `prepare(for segue)` ? It doesn't seem to like it in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Update: I tried to put it in `prepare(for segue)`  but it gives me an error on that as well.  It's almost as if my ModalViewController doesn't recognize the `var`

Comment: FYI your protocol should be `PassColorBackDelegate` - protocols start with a capital as do structs and classes.

Comment: Oops right thanks, I will change them

Comment: @toddg While you're here, since you both seem to know about conventions, would you recommend putting all my protocols and extensions in their own seperate file?  -new to Swift

Comment: Funny you ask, see my response on extensions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42842114/4228969. Not sure about protocols. Most of the time the protocols I write are tightly coupled to one particular class. i.e. think about a UITableViewDelegate. It's so closely linked with a UITableView that it makes sense to have it in the same class. I guess what I'm saying is that protocols aren't as modular/reusable. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the delegate before you perform the segue. Since it sounds like you're using Storyboards, this can be done in `prepare(for segue)`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ModalViewController {
        destinationVC.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Also, as Paul mentioned in the comments, capitalizing your protocols (`PassColorBackProtocol`) and classes (`SubView`) is the conventional style in Swift and helps other people understand your code.

Comment: Thanks! This did it, also I will make sure to capitalize my classes and protocols! Thanks for pointing that out